# cqlsh is failing when executed from docker container

Tags: docker, cassandra, connection, dockerfile, cqlsh

I'm having trouble initializing a Cassandra database in a docker container.
Here's my Dockerfile :

```
FROM cassandra
COPY ./createTable.cql /tmp/createTable.cql
RUN cqlsh -f /tmp/createTable.cql
```

When I do `docker build . -t cassandra`, I get an error at `cqlsh` :

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

But the same commands work fine when I do it outside a Docker container.
Why is the connection refused ? If I'm doing it wrong, how can I initialize my 
database ?

Thanks for any help or advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RUN` is executed when you build the container, not when the container executes.

You need to write custom script that will start Cassandra (same as in original container - look into Cassandra's `Dockerfile`), then wait until it starts, and only after that - execute commands via `cqlsh`.

Comment: As the Dockerfile uses the official cassandra Dockerfile (with the line `FROM cassandra`), there is a Cassandra running inside the container. If I remove the cqlsh command from the Dockerfile, launch it and then run `docker exec -it cassandraContainer cqlsh`, it works

Comment: You're mixing up different things - the `RUN` is executed when you're building the container (I've updated the answer with it) - at this point there is no Cassandra running inside this container... In your case, as you describe, Cassandra is running when you start the container, but this happens only after the container is built.  The second part of my answer suggest how to implement it correctly - this is a standard pattern

Comment: Ok I got it, thanks. I'll try to create a custom script with it. However, why is there an official Dockerfile if the standard pattern is to create your own ? Is it just meant to be used as a template ?

Comment: Standard Dockerfile is used on its own, or could be used as template - but you need to extend it correctly

Comment: I tried doing so but I'm stuck. I check (using `nc -z localhost port`) that the Cassandra port is opened before running `cqlsh`, but the ports are opened before Cassandra is ready, and therefore `cqlsh` crashes. How do you wait for Cassandra to start ?

Answer (score 0):

cqlsh command needs the hostname where the Cassandra is running if the hostname is not provided it will take the localhost (127.0.0.1) as the hostname.

In your case, it's taking localhost as hostname, looks like your   Cassandra is running outside of the container because of that reason it is working fine when you run from outside and failing from inside container.

Passing the hostname to cqlsh should resolve your problem when your run it inside container also.

```
cqlsh <hostname or ip> -f /tmp/createTable.cql
```

Comment: But Cassandra and cqlsh are both running in the container, so it's the localhost. I don't get what you mean, sry